# Buzzing noise in Jamaica Plain

Tags: fallout-4

This is an odd question, but does anyone know where the buzzing noise in Jamaica Plain comes from? It sounds like some electrical device. I'd like to scrap it if it's in the vicinity of the settlement, because it's *extremely* annoying.

Comment: Are there Bloodbugs in the vicinity? Another possibility is a dead ghoul that's glithced near a puddle and splashing constantly.

Comment: I don't think VATS shows any bloodbugs. I'll look for ghouls in puddles; that's a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: I remember hearing a frequent and constant knocking sound there. It turned out it was MacCready in Power Armor trying to fall down to a lower floor, but the engine kept resetting his position to just above the upper floor. He was stuck in between the upper floor and a wall. I just ignored him and continued walking, and he eventually got unstuck by himself.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? (close restart the game)  I have a bug a couple times now I would still hear a enemy turret shooting noise constantly, even after it was destroyed.  Restarting fixed it for me.

Comment: The Nukapedia page on Jamaica Plain mentions turrets. Are you hearing the turret gears going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but the buzz sound you are talking about sounds like a Cicada to me, which means there is probably nothing to scrap.

Go listen to the sound of a Cicada to see if it matches. My ears might just be playing tricks on me but I am pretty sure that is what it is. The sound never bothered me but I can understand how some people would get tired of it.

Comment: I've never heard it in my 74 hours of playing. It doesn't sound like much of a Cicada to me, but I guess it's subjective.

Comment: @Mitch as the original guy said its only in the Jamaica Plain area wonder around there and you might hear it.

Comment: @Mitch I just went and double checked, I can also definitely hear Cicada's in Jamaica Plains.

Comment: For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpCiIYc5nkg

Comment: google videos of "jamaica plain, fallout 4", you will see that there is a bug/cricket sound that gets louder as the player approaches the town. I don't know about cicadas per se, but this is definately something one hears at night in the Midlantic area. When I was in CA recently, my whole family noticed that there "were no bugs." They can get quite loud.

Comment: I've now heard the same sound in other areas, so I guess it's supposed to be cicadas.

Answer (score 2):

You can start off with a map cell reset and see if it removes the noise.  This will hopefully eliminate glitched NPCs causing the sound.

To do a map cell reset, go to a far away area and rest for 30 straight days.  This will be long enough to reset the map.

If the sound persists, then it is a static object/NPC and you'll have to look for it.